# Implementing Google Cloud Speech-to-Text on React-Native

Tags: react-native, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm trying to implement google's speech-to-text on a react native app but I can't find an example or documentation about it, I'm fairly new to react-native so I'm kinda lost, there's a [sample using node.js](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs) on google official docs and I'm trying to 'copy' it to react-native but I didn't had any success.

Here's the Node.js example:

```
async function main() {
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
  const fs = require('fs');

  // Creates a client
  const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

  // The name of the audio file to transcribe
  const fileName = './resources/audio.raw';

  // Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
  const file = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
  const audioBytes = file.toString('base64');

  // The audio file's encoding, sample rate in hertz, and BCP-47 language code
  const audio = {
    content: audioBytes,
  };
  const config = {
    encoding: 'LINEAR16',
    sampleRateHertz: 16000,
    languageCode: 'en-US',
  };
  const request = {
    audio: audio,
    config: config,
  };

  // Detects speech in the audio file
  const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
  const transcription = response.results
    .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
    .join('\n');
  console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
}
main().catch(console.error);
```

First of all, the 'fs' package doesn't work on react-native, so I had to use 'react-native-fs' which has different functions

Second, should I really use the 'require' to call the speech package? I guess react-native would use 'import' instead, right?

Any tips on how can I implement it on react-native? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can't run @google-cloud/speech on react native as RN runs on JV environment and the library (@google-cloud/speech) runs on nodejs environment. You could create an api and deploy it or else use this library [react-native-google-speech-api](https://github.com/hayanmind/react-native-google-speech-api)

Comment: The last commit on this library was 3 years ago. This would require one to eject from an Expo project too, as well. How might one create an api for this so that it is buildable in JS and Expo?